# How to convert datediff & curdate() from MySql to PostgreSQL for a weekly selection range

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have the following SQL query which works fine in MySQL:

```
SELECT floor(datediff(users.created_at, curdate()) / 7) AS weeks_ago,
```

I'm want to convert this from MySQL to PostgreSQL. How can I get this query working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SELECT TRUNC(DATE_PART('day', CURRENT_DATE - users.created_at )/7)  AS weeks_ago
```

If we subtract two DATE or TIMESTAMP in PostgreSQL, we get an interval **"*ddd* days *hh:mi:ss*"**

We can use DATE_PART to extract just the *ddd* value.  (Note that the first argument `'day'` is a string enclosed in single quotes, not a keyword.)

Since the MySQL expression appears to be counting weeks as intervals of 7 days, we can do the same thing in PostgreSQL, divide by 7 and take the integer portion.

(n.b. not tested)

Reference:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT